# Enable smooth scrolling on web page

Tags: javascript, css

I am using [peachananr's onepage-scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) for my project. I have set `responsiveFallback: 1000` and the library "disables" itself at 1000px width. However, (noticeable on a touch device) the scrolling is not restored to normal (smooth scrolling). It stops as soon as I lift my finger (sticky scroll). What is causing this?

Comment: `What is causing this?` - you lift your finger

Comment: Wow. Geez. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: Wash your sticky hands before touching your screen. ;o) (Sorry, could not resist.)

Comment: Some code examples would be useful, particularly where you setup the scrolling stuff

Comment: Sure. Please view on a touch device and then scroll: http://jsbin.com/bapesacesi

Comment: Have you though about using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead ?